# Alocar memoria dinamica com várias strings

Tags: c

O meu objetivo é alocar memoria "para baixo", fazendo um genero de uma matriz, em que o comprimento da string é estático **MaxLength** e o numero de strings que se coloca é usada memoria dinamica.

```
#define MaxLength 35
typedef struct{
    char RoomName[MaxLength];
    char *SensorName[MaxLength];
    unsigned int SensorCount;
    char *Actuador[MaxLength];
    unsigned int ActuadorCount;
}DataStruct;



void ToSensorName(DataStruct *Data, char *token){
    Data->SensorCount++;
    printf("Count inicial: %d", Data->SensorCount);


    Data->SensorName[MaxLength]=  realloc(Data->SensorName[MaxLength], Data->SensorCount * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(Data->SensorName[Data->SensorCount-1], token);

    printf("\n\nFuncao: %s  count: %d\n\n",Data->SensorName[Data->SensorCount-1], Data->SensorCount);

}
 void ToStruct(DataStruct *Data, char *token, short *count){

        switch(*count){

        case 0:
            strcpy(Data->RoomName, token);
            printf("\n->%s<-", Data->RoomName);
            break;
        case 1:
            ToSensorName(Data, token);
            break;
        case 2:
            *count= -1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error count");
            break;
    }


    (*count)++;
    }
```

**Problema:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Na função *ToSensorName* o valor de SensorCount diminui
- Na main quando volto a chamar imprime como null, ou seja, é porque não estou a colocar o valor por referencia.

---

```
int main()
{
    DataStruct Data;
    Data.SensorCount=0;
    Data.ActuadorCount=0;
    const char *filename="SensorConfigurations.txt";
    char buff[MaxBuffer];
    FILE *SensorConviguration;
    SensorConviguration=fopen(filename, "r");
    if(SensorConviguration==NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename );
        return 1;
    }
    char *token;
    short count=0;

    while(fgets(buff, MaxBuffer, SensorConviguration)!= NULL)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", buff);
        system("PAUSE");
        /* get the first token */
        token = strtok(buff, ":");
        /*POSSIVEL PROBLEMA*/
        ToStruct(&Data, token, &count);
        /* walk through other tokens */
        while( token != NULL )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", token );
            token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        }

    }
   /*POSSIVEL PROBLEMA*/
    printf("\n\n\nMain: %s", Data.SensorName[0]);
    fclose(SensorConviguration);
    return 0;
}
```

Obs: Já tentei procurar uma pergunta parecida que me ajudasse aqui, porém acabo por não conseguir solucionar o problema.